# Spring boot authorization issue with fetching roles from Azure AD auth server

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

As per this we implemented Spring boot auth with Azure AD: https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html

Here the access token validation works fine but not showing any authorities:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();        
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authoritiesFromToken = authentication.getAuthorities();              
System.out.println("authoritiesFromToken:  " + authoritiesFromToken);
```

The following dependencies are used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Added app roles in Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

Used Postman to get the Azure AD token with client credentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token

After this run the application but the app roles set to the application is not printed.

What we need to do to get the roles as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sometimes  token is an access token may not be  for your app. The
  roles you are looking for can be present  in the id token.
- Please make sure to check both id token and access token in
  authentication blade or try by checking both individually.

[image]

- As you were not able to access the roles in your token. Please check
  if you  were not assigning a **resource** in  request parameters
  along with (client_id, grant_type, etc.) . By default the resource
  maybe something like  00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. Also try by sending
  responseType =token  in the request.

Please check this [Azure AD-protected Web API using Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory (aaddevsup.xyz)](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2021/06/azure-ad-protected-web-api-using-spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory/)

Add the following dependencies to your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
   // <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

According to note here in [Add app roles and get them from a token - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#declare-roles-for-an-application)

> **Note:** Currently ***if you add a service principal to a group, and then assign an app role to that group, Azure AD does not add the roles
> claim to tokens it issues***. Azure AD emits a roles claim for each role
> that the user or service principal has been granted individually to
> the user and the user's group memberships.

The roles could also be added directly in the manifest json file.

```
"appRoles": [
{
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User , Applications"
    ],
    "description": " ",
    "displayName": " ",
    "id": "<Guid> ",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "lang": null,
    "origin": "<> ",
    "value": "  "
},
]
```

> If you're implementing app role business logic in an app-calling-API
> scenario, you have two app registrations. One app registration is for
> the app, and a second app registration is for the API. ***In this case,
> define the app roles and assign them to the user or group in the app
> registration of the API.*** When the user authenticates with the app and
> requests an access token to call the API, a roles claim is included in
> the access token. Your next step is to add code to your web API to
> check for those roles when the API is called.

Check the user.read is for graph api and to get token for api for your app should have the scope exposed for api.and granted api permissions for admin consent.

To learn how to add authorization to your web API, see [Protected web API: Verify scopes and app roles.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles)

**Reference :**
[Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory developer's guide | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide)

Answer (score 1):

we need add
`scope: openid,profile`
in application.yml file to get the profile information of user.